# Is my hardware configuration enough for Ubuntu 64 bit?

Tags: 14.04, 64-bit, laptop, hardware

I use Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 32 bit version, and I'm thinking to install the 64 bit version.

Is that a good idea with this configuration?[image: Latpop hardware configuration]

Comment: [This](http://askubuntu.com/questions/26851/should-i-install-64-bit-ubuntu-if-my-hardware-supports-it?rq=1) page describes the considerations of switching to 64-bit well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same question, but  I can say to you that I installed Ubuntu 14.04 64bits version on my PC with acceptable behavior.

This is my hardware configuration

Memory:  2.9 GiB

Procesador:   Intel® Core™2 Duo CPU E4600 @ 2.40GHz × 2

Graphic card:  GeForce GT 610/PCIe/SSE2

What is the behavior of you laptop?

Comment: I'm still using the 32bits version.